# Its possible to link a group of 1/4 W resistors as an alternative to a resistor with a high power rating (1.25 W)?

Tags: resistors, resistance, parallel, series, watts

I have 10 resistors. Each one is 10 Ω. Is it possible to reach 3.3 Ω with a power rating of 1.25 or 1.5 W?

I tried to get 3.3 Ω by linking in parallel (3 resistors), but the power rating is not high enough and I can't put more in parallel because the resistance will become very small.

Edit :now i have 30 resistor of 10Ω
And also i have these resistor :

https://www.uruktech.com/product/30-values-600pcs-resistor/

Comment: Well, if you really need 3.3 Ohms and not 4 Ohms, for example, then no. You could put 4 series-pairs of 20 Ohms in parallel with one 10 Ohm to get 3.3 Ohms. (5 Ohms in parallel with 10 Ohms is 3.3 Ohms.) But the isolated 10 Ohm resistor will be experiencing 4X the dissipation of the others. You could clamp something onto it to help it dissipate better. But probably not enough. Do you mind sharing the reason you cannot just get the right resistor?

Comment: @periblepsis i edit the question... Now is there any chance or its the same thing?

Comment: Gbarry's answer is then the right one, I suspect. Just use the 12 resistors he indicates.

Comment: @Pcp115 please don't invalidate the answers by suddenly changing the question to require different answers.

Comment: @Pcp115 Just make (6) 20 Ohm resistors (using two 10 Ohm resistors in series) and put them in parallel. Done. About 100 mW each. So well within their capability.

Comment: @periblepsis i dont have 20ohm (only have 22ohm)

Comment: @Pcp115 But if you add two 10 Ohm, you get 20 Ohm.

Comment: @Pcp115 - Hi, You really should not have changed your question after anyone had posted an answer. That has caused there to be some answers addressing your original question & some which now address the updated version. It is not fair on those who answered your original question, that their answers now look incomplete / wrong because you changed the question. I can't reverse your edit without also affecting the answers which addressed that edit. In short, it's a mess. Please don't edit a question so it invalidates existing answer(s) again. See the term "chameleon question" on [meta.se]. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you add another 3 in parallel you will now have a 1.65 ohm resistor.  Make another one just like it, and put these two bundles in series.  They add up to 3.3 ohms.  Only thing is, this requires 12 resistors, which is two more than you have.   Total wattage is 12 * 0.25, or 3 watts.

Comment: with a 5-parallel, 2-series array, its possible to get 4 ohms with 10x wattage. Maybe that's still acceptable.

Answer (score 5):

**TLDR; No, you cannot do it with the components you have to hand**

Proof

You have 1/4 watt, 10 Ω resistors

As power = I<sup>2</sup>R, you can calculate the maximum voltage and current permitted at any resistor as 158 mA and 1.58 V.

You want to make a 3.3 Ω resistor with a power rating of 1.25 W or 1.5 W.

Solving I<sup>2</sup>R = P for these resistors gives you 615 mA and 2.03 V for the 1.25 W resistor, and 674 mA and 2.22 V for the 1.5 W resistor.

You will need at least two resistors in series to keep the voltage across the 10 Ω resistors within limits.

You will need at least 4 resistors in parallel to meet the current requirements for the 1.25 W resistor, and 5 in parallel for the 1.5 W resistor.

A 2S5P array only gets you down to 4 Ω

You need a 2S6P to get down to 3.3 Ω, two more resistors than you have.

You can use an irregular connection of resistors. I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader to convince themselves that you can't break the overall voltage and current limits with an irregular array, although you will get some slightly different resistance values.

edit - in response to an edit of the question - as you have at least 12 resistors, a 2S6P arrangement gives you a 3.33 Ω 3 watt resistor. With 30 resistors to hand, you can make two of those.

As the values in your extra 600 pack start 10, 22, 47 Ω, there's not a lot of scope. 6 x 22 Ω in parallel will get you 1.5 watts and 3.66 Ω, which needs only a 36 Ω resistor in parallel to bring it down to 3.33 Ω. Your pack doesn't have a 36 Ω resistor.

There is a systematic way to approximate values from a set of resistors. The equation for two resistors a and b in parallel is 1/(1/a + 1/b), which on most calculators means a finger dance of a, 1/x, +b, 1/x, =, 1/x. Not many people invert this process to find the resistor that you need to put in parallel with another one to make a target value. That resistor is 1/(1/a - 1/b), a similar finger dance on the calculator with -b instead of +b.

Let's do this with your values. Your 6 x 22 Ω resistors come to 3.666 Ω. Your target is 3.333, which requires a 36.66 Ω resistor. You don't have one in your set, but you do have a 47 Ω above it. Put that in parallel to get 3.401 Ω. What does that need to get 3.33 Ω? 166.7 Ω There isn't that value in the set, the next above is 200 Ω. Put that in parallel, and we get to 3.344 Ω. Close enough? If not, we now need 1028 Ω. We'll use 1000 Ω to get to 3.333 Ω. In theory, we know we could get closer and closer by using more resistors. In practice, these are only 1% resistors, so looking beyond the second decimal place is dubious, and beyond the third is a waste of time and false precision.

further edit - you should of course never plan to run your resistors at their power rating, for reliability. When I designed industrial equipment, a 50% resistor power derating was standard. The ambient, and nearby dissipation affects resistor temperatures and so reliability. If you make this 2S6P resistor pack, mount the resistors a distance from each other so they each see a cooling ambient. The worst thing to do would be to twist 6 resistors together as a convenient way to put them into parallel.

/edits

Comment: i edit the question... Now is there any chance or its the same thing?

Comment: `Your target is 3.333` not quite: `reach 3.3 Ω`.

Answer (score 5):

I think the below are as close as you can get to the requested numbers with what you have. Two more 10Ω resistors will allow you get 3.33Ω with 3W allowable dissipation, of course.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYKykM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The first one is 0.75w (not 3w)

Comment: Just use 12 10Ω resistors in series-parallel (same as the 2nd circuit above but with one more series pair) and you will have 3.33Ω with a 3W allowable dissipation. If this is a real exercise you should keep the resistors separated a bit (one or two diameters maybe) since they're not actually good for 0.25W if they are being heated a lot by other parts. The maximum rating will be at something like 70°C or less ambient.

Comment: you can acheive 750 mW with just 3 x 10 ohms in parallel, the limitation being the voltage across R9

Comment: @Neil_UK better for simplicity but perhaps worse for reliability with more stressed parts.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I think the subtleties of designing for soft fail are beyond the scope of this question. I've treated it as a straight maths puzzle, with hard rating. If we want to get into which components will fail first with what consequence, then we should really talk about derating first, and the requirements of the actual application, to see whether a shift in value is a permissible fail. I'll update my answer with a brief line on derating.